# Using library symbols after publishing with Flash CC 2015

Tags: javascript, flash, canvas, symbols, createjs

I want to use Flash CC 2015 for exporting symbols from library to use them after.

I have some symbols in my labrary:

http://clip2net.com/s/3mTS0lg

But I can't find them in the generated .js file (after publishing):

http://clip2net.com/s/3mTSd2D

I am not sure if it is possible, but maybe somebody knows how to use symbols from library in JS without placing them on the main Timeline?

Thanks!

P.S.: Sorry for the links instead of images, I don't have enough reputation for posting images =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually edit the "linkage" field in the library (doesn't look editable but it is), and the symbol will be exported with that name.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/flUjV.jpg